# UmbracoExamine ParentID?

Tags: c#, umbraco7, examine

I'm currently using UmbracoExamine for all of my project's search needs, and I'm trying to figure out what exactly the query-parameter ".ParentId" does.

I was hoping I could use it to find all child nodes from a parentID, but I can't seem to get it working.

Basically, if the searchstring contains e.g. "C# Programming", it should find all that category's articles. This is just an example.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say it should find all "that category's" articles I assume you have a structure like the below?

```
-- Programming
----Begin Java Programming
----Java Installation on Linux
----Basics of C# Programming
----What is SDLC
----Advanced C# Programming
-- Sports
----Baseball basics
```

If so then I assume as well that you want all the articles under "programming" to be listed and not just those containing "C# Programming"?

What you will need to do is to loop through the SearchResults from your query and find the parent node from there

```
IPublishedContent node = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current).TypedContent(item.Fields["id"].ToString());
IPublishedContent parentNode = node.Parent;
```

Once you have the parent node you can get all it's children as well as some of them depending on document type and what you want to do

```
IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> allChildren = parentNode.Children;
IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> specificChildren = parentNode.Children.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("aliasOfSomeDocType"));
```

Example code below

```
    //Fetching what eva searchterm some bloke is throwin' our way
    string q = Request.QueryString["search"].Trim();

    //Fetching our SearchProvider by giving it the name of our searchprovider
    Examine.Providers.BaseSearchProvider Searcher = Examine.ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["SiteSearchSearcher"];

    // control what fields are used for searching and the relevance
    var searchCriteria = Searcher.CreateSearchCriteria(Examine.SearchCriteria.BooleanOperation.Or);
    var query = searchCriteria.GroupedOr(new string[] { "nodeName", "introductionTitle", "paragraphOne", "leftContent", "..."}, q.Fuzzy()).Compile();        

    //Searching and ordering the result by score, and we only want to get the results that has a minimum of 0.05(scale is up to 1.)
    IEnumerable<SearchResult> searchResults = Searcher.Search(query).OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).TakeWhile(x => x.Score > 0.05f);  

    //Printing the results
    foreach (SearchResult item in searchResults)
    {
        //get the parent node
        IPublishedContent node = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current).TypedContent(item.Fields["id"].ToString());
        IPublishedContent parentNode = node.Parent;

        //if you wish to check for a particular document type you can include this
        if (item.Fields["nodeTypeAlias"] == "SubPage")
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for getting back to me. This is pretty much how I ended up doing it, but I'm going to wait for other answers as I would love to see a solution that doesn't require us to filter the results after having fetched them. Much better if we can only index the results we need rather than getting them all at once, then filtering them by parent ID afterwards.

I hope I'm making sense. Once again, thanks!

Comment: I don't think the parent Id is at the moment available from the Index Attribute Fields

Comment: Yeah, that's why I ended up filtering the results after fetching them. It works fine for this scenario. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool, hopefully it will be included soon, then the filtering can fall away